# Spring JPA / HIbernate - Foreign key is never set

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have 2 Oracle tables in a 1:M relationship:

```sql
EVENT(ID, NAME, DATE)

EVENT_LOG(ID, EVENT_ID, COMPLETED)
```

- EVENT has PK=ID
- EVENT_LOG has PK=ID and FK=EVENT_ID on EVENT.ID

I want to use Spring JPA to persist this data to database, so I build my entities with `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations like below (some details omitted for clarity):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT")
public class EventEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DATE"")
    private OffsetDateTime date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "eventEntityDetails", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EventLogEntity> eventLogs;
    
    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT_LOG")
public class EventLogEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "EVENT_ID")
    private long eventId;

    @Column(name = "COMPLETED")
    private int completed;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "E_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private EventEntity eventEntityDetails;

    // ...
}
```

In order to persist my EVENT and EVENT_LOG, I have this method.  It receives EntityDto object which I map to a new instance of Entity and then I create new EventLogEntity, set its `COMPLETED` value and call repository to save my event.

At this stage, I cannot set the EventLog.EVENT_ID as at this stage EVENT.ID has not been generated, so my expectation is that hibernate takes care of that for me.  However that turns to be wrong and I think I am missing something either in this method or in my `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations above in my entities:

```java
private EventEntity saveEvent(EventDto eventDto) {

    EventEntity eventEntity = new EventEntity();

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.map(eventDto, eventEntity);

    List<EventLogEntity> eventLogs = new ArrayList<EventLogEntity>();

    EventLogEntity eventLogEntity = new EventLogEntity();
    eventLogEntity.setCompleted(1);
    eventLogs.add(eventLogEntity);

    eventEntity.setEventtLogs(eventLogs);

    EventEntity storedEvent = eventRepository.saveAndFlush(eventEntity);

    return storedEvent;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

The above call to `safeAndFlush()` will save my Event and EventLog to their tables, however EVENT_LOG.EVENT_ID (which is the FK to EVENT.ID) is always set 0 instead of being set to the value in EVENT.ID.

I would expect it to be set to the ID of EVENT like in example below:

```sql
EVENT(1, 'open_door', 20220210T11:55:10)

EVENT_LOG(1, 1, 1)
```

, but instead, I get:

```sql
EVENT(1, 'open_door', 20220210T11:55:10)

EVENT_LOG(1, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to assign the `EventEntity` object to the `EventLogEntity` before flushing:

```
EventLogEntity eventLogEntity = new EventLogEntity();
eventLogEntity.setCompleted(1);
eventLogEntity.setEventEntityDetails(eventEntity);
eventLogs.add(eventLogEntity);
```

See if that helps.

**Update**:
I think what you want is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT")
public class EventEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EventLogEntity> eventLogs;
    
    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT_LOG")
public class EventLogEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID")
    private EventEntity event;

}
```

Notice a few things here:

- I removed the `referencedColumnName` info because by default the primary key of the referencing table is used, which is fine in our case
- I removed the explicit `EVENT_ID` column which you declared as part of the class. This column will be created automatically as part of attaching the `@ManyToOne` annotation on the `event` field.
- I renamed the `eventEntityDetails` field simply to `event`

I am pretty sure the solution will work! Please let me know.

Comment: Thanks but still did not update EVENT_LOG.EVENT_ID.  It is still 0.  All I see now is a new field added to EVENT_LOG called E_ID like `EVENT_LOG(ID, EVENT_ID, COMPLETED, E_ID) = (1, 0, 1, 1)`.  So, this new field E_ID is getting the value of the EVENT.ID looks like but not the EVENT_LOG.EVENT_ID which is the FK that should get it.`

Comment: Hi pixel, I updated my answer :) I think I understand now what your problem was. You do not need to declare a separate `EVENT_ID` column, but the FK column will be created automatically if you declare the `@JoinColumn` annotation

Comment: Thank you.  That does work, much appreciated.  The only issue I am having now thought is that my MockMvc test for persisting EVENT is failiing as it expected to get EVENT Json object (the way it is sent to the API) but that JSON object knows nothing about the EVENT_LOG since that is not something that should be sent to the API.  I'll create new SO for that thought.  Much appreciated for your help.

Comment: @yasper Would you be able to help with this one?  Your solution worked fine on H2 but it fails with Oracle DB.  I created new SO at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73535617/spring-jpa-hibernate-persisting-to-h2-works-fine-but-fails-with-oracle-with  Thank you

Comment: This solution is great, thank you.  I have cought up on some readings about hibernate.  This method is creating a bi-directionaly association.  Would same work with uni-directional association where only owning (EVENT) entity has `@OneToMany` annotation?  Thanks again